# How to programically inject a dependency to N classes in Symfony2? Can I somehow inherit injected services?

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, symfony-2.3

In my app I am generating `n` number of classes. They all have the same skeleton and serve a similar purpose. They also share dependencies.

Instead of adding `n` entries in `services.xml` like so:

```
    <service id="acme.security.first_voter" class="Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\FirstVoter" public="false">
        <tag name="security.voter" />
        <argument type="service" id="logger" />
    </service>
    <service id="acme.security.second_voter" class="Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\SecondVoter" public="false">
        <tag name="security.voter" />
        <argument type="service" id="logger" />
    </service>
```

I'd like to simply add one entry like this:

```
    <service id="acme.security.base_voter" class="Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\BaseVoter" public="false">
        <tag name="security.voter" />
        <argument type="service" id="logger" />
    </service>
```

and in each Voter simply add

```
use Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\BaseVoter;

class FirstVoter extends BaseVoter
```

But that does not work.

I've seen [Managing Common Dependencies with Parent Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html), but it does not solve my issue, becouse it requires I add a

```
<service id="acme.security.first_voter" class="Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\FirstVoter" parent="base_voter"/>
<service id="acme.security.second_voter" class="Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\SecondVoter" parent="base_voter"/>
```

for each voter... but thats exacly what I'm trying to avoid, becouse `n` can be 5 or.. 500.

I've read some old Richard Miller blog posts about injecting a dependency into an interface, and all classes implementing that interface would "inherit injected dependencies" (also be injected that service). Thats exacly what I need! Unfortunately, this has been dropped for some reason and it does not work for Symfony2.3.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: what this basevoter does? because if it is a kind of "dispatcher" for correct class, you can inject it and create a method for retrieve the correct voter.

Comment: base voter holds 15 common methods I will use in other voters

Comment: and my solutions isn't suitable? You can make each voter extend the base voter, inject base voter and, when you need a certain kind of voter, pass a parameter (i.e.: class name, or a placeholder) to your service (base voter) that will act pretty much like a factory method pattern.

Comment: could you explain more..? i don't fully understand what your solution is about, maybe some example code i could see to try and understand?

Comment: @loostro what about the compilerpass solution? easy implementation automatic finding/registering of your inherited voters - that's what you want right?

Comment: @nifr yes, but where should i add a compiler pass? if i have my BaseClass in BaseBundle, and some classes extending BaseClass are in MyCustomBundle (ChildClass1, ChildClass2) and MyCustomBundle2 (ChildClass3, ChildClass4, ChildClass5).... where should I have the compiler pass? In BaseBundle, MyCustomBundle or MyCustomBundle2?

Comment: @nifr if i understand correct how DIC works, then if symfony2 uses ChildClass4 it will load MyCustomBundle2 configuration (becouse this class is in this bundle).. but adding a CompilerPass to each bundle that can have classes extending BaseClass -> thats not solving a problem, only moveing it elsewhere

Comment: @nifr if I could define "All classes extending Acme\MyBundle\BaseClass (no matter in which bundle they are) should be injected @logger" in one place that would be what im looking for

Comment: I suggest the compilerpass belongs into your basebundle ... and yes you can look for all classes extending your baseclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can well use [parent services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html) for this purpose.

You just have to register them all using a [CompilerPass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#creating-a-compiler-pass) instead of adding each one manually.

Use the Finder component to search all bundle's i.e. Voter folder for classes extending your base voter - then register them in the CompilerPass.

Improve by caching your results for performance reasons :)

---

Or you use [JMSDiExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations#service)

```
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;

/**
 * @Service("some.service.id", parent="another.service.id", public=false)
 */
class Voter extends BaseVoter
{
}
```

It basically does exactly that ( using a [compilerpass](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AnnotationConfigurationPass.php) ).

Comment: Good solution, but "advanced" one :) +1

Comment: compilerpasses are dope! i use them often to register translations and assetic collections without touching config files :)

Comment: I'm currently reading and understanding whole process of compilerpasses and I find them very interesting

Comment: @nifr nice i didn't think about useing finder, but then again, in which bundle should my compiler pass be? in BaseBundle i guess? will it's configuration be read (and thus.. MyDiffrentBundle/Voter/ChildVoterX will be defined as service) if the request is routed to MyDiffrentBundle?

Comment: basically this is what JMSDiExtraBundle does ... i have updated my answer.